# Django, Integrity error with PK, but new objects are still working fine

Tags: python, django, django-models, model, integrity

So here's my view

```py
def add_tutorial(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        User = request.POST.get('user')
        # other properties
        lang = request.POST.get('lang')

        new_tutorial = Tutorial.objects.create(
            User=User, ..., lang=lang)

    context = {
        'page_title': 'create tutorial',
    }

    return render(request, "add-tutorial.html")
```

I do create a `tutorial` with forms, it all works well, I can see the tutorial where it needs to be, but for some reason I get integrity error regarding the pk

`IntegrityError at /add_tutorial. UNIQUE constraint failed: main_tutorial.id`

The Id in the db is correct (i use sqlight).

Before I used to specify the id in the create function, but now it shouldn't be any problem since I've dropped that db and (properly) undone all migrations; nothing changed

[the only meaningful traceback that i get is to the `Tutorial.objects.create(...)` line]

here's my model for the tutorial

````py
class Tutorial(models.Model):
    '''
Tutorial is a list of lessons\n
name, is_done, length, num_of_tests, description, is_public, lang'''

    # lessons = what #! list of 'links' of lessons
    # lessons = models.
    User = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name='tutorial_author', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, validators=[MinLengthValidator(
        10, 'should be at least 10 characters long')])
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=user_directory_path, default='def_tn.png')

    xlength = models.IntegerField(editable=False, null=True, default=0)
    num_of_tests = models.IntegerField(
        editable=False, null=True)  # somehow add a function to it
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True)
    is_public = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=True, null=True)
    lang = models.CharField(max_length=16, choices=lang_choices, default='eng')

    urlid = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, default='')

    created = models.DateTimeField(
        editable=False, null=True, auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(editable=False, null=True, auto_now=True)
    ```
````

Comment: Likely the "sequence" of the primary key (the thing the database uses to dispatch primary keys) is out of sync with the items you use. For some databases you can restart the database, for others you will need to update the sequence to start by the maximum of the primary keys already dispatched + 1.

Comment: I've dropped the entire database, and unapplied all migrations [only in this app though]
but it's still exactly the same problem.

Should I then, do something like:

`new_id = Tutorial.objects.all()[-1].id
new_tutorial = Tutorial.objects.create(id=new_id, ...)`

what if the last object gets deleted, then the new one would be have an Id of an already deleted object [so object #20 is created, then immidiately deleted, so then the next one would have id of 20, which isn't good afaik]

Comment: can you share the model, what do you use as primary key field (`UUIDField`?)

Comment: I didn't write any id field manually [so only properties like User, name, description..]
is that the problem?

Comment: can you share the model and the app config?

Comment: I've added models [don't know what else could be usefull]

Comment: any updates on this, facing the same issue!